# Cassandra encryption at rest

Tags: encryption, cassandra

I need to store some sensitive data in Cassandra and require it to be encrypted at rest. Is it likely Cassandra would function normally on top of a Linux encrypted file system (something like the open source [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) product)?

The other alternative available is to do the encryption at the application layer before sending the data to Cassandra but that entails writing plumbing code, and security plumbing code at that, which it would be good to avoid if at all possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great question! There's a handful of
ways of doing this, depending on how deeply you want to be involved in
the configuration and long term maintenance.  You certainly could use
Cassandra on top of an encrypted filesystem, such as TrueCrypt or
eCryptfs, and it should function normally.

While possible, it's a little complicated to set up encrypted
filesystem and enforce a secure key management scheme.  [Gazzang](http://www.gazzang.com) offers
a commercial product built on top of eCryptfs which provides a turnkey
[Encryption & Key Management Platform](http://www.securingbigdata.com) that would keep all of your
Cassandra data secure, without requiring any changes to your existing
database applications.  Gazzang has a custom-tailored "jumpstart"
documentation for Cassandra that simplifies and assist in your
encryption/security implementation for Cassandra.

*Full disclosure: I am employed by Gazzang.*

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the SafeNet Key Management and Encryption platform. They have various key and audit / compliance technologies. They support many other databases and file systems. We use it for application encryption but they have various integration points.